# Git - Forgot to switch branch

Tags: git, windows-7, tortoisegit

I forgot to switch to a new branch before beginning my project, and now I need to push my changes to a new branch (not master) in order for another to review my work. My work is finsihed, but saved in my local master.

How can I move my changes into a new branch, so when I push it doesnt mess with the master branch but instead create a new remote branch ?

Comment: Have you committed all of your work yet? If so, is it just one commit or a series of commits?

Comment: I believe so, and it would be a series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what happened, but when I followed the git commands by KurzedMetal it didnt give me the desired result.

So I saw no other option than re-doing my changes, despite having taken a backup prior to doing a hard reset back to *remote master* as well as my export of changed files. Both the export and the backup were worthless as they contained the exact same content as my local repository afterwards, thus my changes were **lost**. I had expected **both** to be unchanged.

Luckily, I had stashed my changes before I began on my push problem.
***Note***: Newly created files were not removed after the hard reset.

Here are my steps to fix:

1. Finished you changes (still in *master*)
2. Pull new changes from *remote master* and fix any conflicts
3. `TortoiseGit -> Stash save`. Enter a message to distinct it from other stashes -> Ok
4. `TortoiseGit -> Show log`. Select newest master, then right-click and select `Reset`, then the `Hard option` -> Ok
5. `TortoiseGit -> Create Branch`. Enter a name and check the box `Switch to new branch` -> Ok
6. `TortoiseGit -> Stash list`. Select your saved stash -> Ok
7. Now you see a list of different files. For each file, compare the differences and apply the changes again to newly reset files
8. When done, right-click inside your local folder. You should see `Git Commit -> "BranchName" ...` above `TortoiseGit`, choose the first
9. Confirm which files to commit and then enter a fitting description -> Ok
10. Now you are ready to `push`. `TortoiseGit -> Push`, check that the local branch is your chosen name. If its not, then you forgot to switch branch in 5. and have to continue from 6.

I hope this will help others. The thing to remember: Switch to a new branch when you begin a new feature / non-minor change

Comment: `git stash` would work only if you didn't commit anything, and you stated that you already committed multiple times.

Comment: I said `I believe`. As you can guess, I am still very much new to working with repositories. On a side, I got `Git Bash` working - all I had to was to navigate to my repo folder using `cd` command as `Git Bash` apparently doesnt start in my repo folder, thus it had no hidden "git" folder to check against.

Comment: I'd recommend you to read the [online Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/) if you wanna feel fluid using git, It's short, has neat graphs representing how git see your data and iseasy to understand. It helped me a lot when i started.

Answer (score 15):

First, since you have done all your work your local master branch, create a new feature branch pointing to the tip or your local master.

```
$ git checkout -b newfeature master
```

and then leave the master as it is in the server (remote)

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Im using just the GUI (Git Bash gives me errors). I did "Create branch" and selected "HEAD", "[ ] Switch to new branch" was not checked. Then I opened the log, selected the newest master entry and picked "Reset" then "Hard". Looking at the files I see my changes are gone, but when I switch to the new branch and ask to see "Diff" nothing shows up! Shouldnt they have been there ?

Comment: @Kim I'm not sure what you did in the GUI, those steps work no matter where you do them, you must have skipped a step. It's really hard for me to help you if you are using only the GUI, i have almost no experience with `git gui` as i hate the Tk interface. Remember that branches and tags are only pointers to a commit, git actually doesn't delete anything until garbage collection. If you lost any changes doing this steps, you can look at `git relog` to recover your previous commits.

Comment: Instead of using checkout to create the branch, you could just do a
`git branch newfeature` then you just need to do the `git reset --hard origin/master`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch at the same point as your master.

Checkout the master, and hard reset your current branch to the commit you want to rewind to.